# Handling keyboard interaction in a game loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keyboard-events

I am playing with javascript and writing a simple game. I have a game loop set up and want to use the arrow keys to interact with the game. I have defined an event handler to handle keyboard interaction and placed this before and outside the main game loop, along with the definition for the game interval (tick) timer:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var_to_modify = processKeys(event);
});

let gameTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    gameLoop();
}, gameSpeed);

function gameLoop() {
    ...
}
```

The game loop ticks over nicely but the problem is this: how can I take the result of the processKeys() function and use it to modify a variable that is used inside the gameLoop() function?
I know this can be achieved using a global, e.g. a game state variable, but is there a more elegant solution without using a global variable?
Ta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a closure around game loop :

```
function generateGameLoop() {
let param = 0; //or any default value
let setParam = function (newParam) { 
param = newParam;
//here add any logic to respond to event
};
let gameLoop = function() {
    ...
}
return {setParam, gameLoop};
}

let setParam, gameLoop = generateGameLoop();

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    setParam(processKeys(event));
});

let gameTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
    gameLoop();
}, gameSpeed);
```

I would also rename gameLoop as gameStep or gameIncrement or whatever.

(code might be wrong but the goal is to give you an idea)

Comment: Many thanks for the advice but any chance you could explain what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: line 13 you call generateGameLoop() which creates an instance of param variable, an instance of setParam() function and gameLoop() function. The param variable, after generateGameLoop()  returns, will no longer be accesible. But it still lives and is accessed by setParam and gameLoop inner code everytime you call one of these function references. Thats why you keep a reference to these functions by assigning them to the variables setParam and gameLoop in line 13. Then you assign these references to setParam as eventListener and to gameLoop as the function to be called repeatedly by setInterval

Comment: The whole idea is to have your "var_to_modify" variable replaced by a variable (here "param") which lives inside a closure so as to be sure that this variable can only be accessed through the given setParam and gameLoop functions. For more details look up articles explaining javascript "closures"

Comment: That's great. Thanks for taking the time to explain this. It helped me complete the game! :-)